# Find the kernel of the group homomorphism $G\to\text{Bij}(G/H),\;a\mapsto(b\mapsto abH)$

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a group and $H\subset G$ be a subgroup. Find the kernel of the group homomorphism $$G\to\text{Bij}(G/H),\;a\mapsto(b\mapsto abH)$$

Comment: I'm confused.. What is $Bij(G/H)$?

Comment: @Exodd It's likely the set of all bijections from the set of cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Comment: It's the bijections of $G/H\to G/H$

Comment: how is the map defined by $b\mapsto abH$ a bijection on $G/H$?  Do you mean $bH\mapsto abH$?

Comment: Also, you don't want $abH=e$, but $abH=bH$ for all $b\in H$, so that the left multiplication by $a$ on the cosets is the identity function.

Comment: So is it just $a=e$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

The kernel is 
$$\bigcap_{g \in G} g H g^{-1}$$
the intersection of all the conjugates of $H$ i. e. the largest normal subgroup $G$ contained in $H$ ( also called the normal core of $H$). (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_%28group%29)

Answer (score 0):

Kernel = {$a \in G : bH \to abH=bH , $ i.e $b^{-1}ab \in H$ $\forall b \in G$} . If $H$ is normal in $G$, then kernel becomes $H$ itself.